# When to use message passing in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a fairly standard use case wherein I have popup.html and background.js in a chrome extension. I need to do 2 things

1. When the user clicks on a button in popup, let background.js know about it
2. Send some data from background to popup

Now to implement these features I was thinking on the lines of using [long-lived connections](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#connect) as outlined in the chrome extension docs. To that measure, this is what I have

```
# popup.js

var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "LOGGERCHANNEL"});

function sendMessage(msg) {
  port.postMessage(msg);
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) { 
    console.log("message recieved"+ msg); 
  });
}

sendMessage("hello world");


# background_page.js

chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  console.log("Connected to Popup");
  console.assert(port.name == "LOGGERCHANNEL");


  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
    console.log('Background got message:', msg);
  });
});
```

This works perfectly fine, however, I am at a loss on how to accomplish a `sendMessage` function for `background.js` as well. Ideally, I would like to do `sendMessage('hello from bg')` when a certain event occurs? How would this be possible?

Secondly, as outlined in [this answer](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-extensions/1b1FryZ_2oA) I can simply use `chrome.extension.getViews()` and `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()` to accomplish this task, by sharing variables.

Which is recommended approach for solving this kind of a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you are trying to do something like - get/set options between background and popup. This is how I handled that:

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  chrome.extension.sendMessage({"msg":"getOptions"}, function(response){
    $('#clientId').val(response.options.clientId);
  });

  $("#setOptions" ).on("click", function(){
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({
      "msg":"saveOptions",
      "options":{ "clientId" : $('#clientId').val() }
    }); //sengMessage
  }); //on

}); //addEventListener
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.msg == "getOptions") {
    var options = {
      clientId : localStorage.getItem('clientId') || ""
    };
    sendResponse({"msg" : "setOptions", "options" : options})
  }
```

in some cases `sendResponse` will not work, i.e. when reading cookies from background page, so instead of using it you would `sendMessage` instead.